# Though user HDFS is owner of a Dir, I'm unable to view all the directories

Tags: linux, hadoop

As HDFS user (owner of a Dir), I'm unable to view all the directories
Here is a command sample:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-33-161 ~]$ ls -ltr
drwxrwxrwx  2 hdfs     hadoop   4096 Oct  7 22:39 cards2
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-33-161 ~]$ sudo su - hdfs
[hdfs@ip-172-31-33-161 ec2-user]$ ls -ltr
ls: cannot open directory .: Permission denied
```

Comment: are you trying to access the same folder location?? can you issue a `pwd` command as both users?

Comment: I got it, after executing PWD Command. I was executing the command in /home/ec2-user instead of /home/hdfs. Thanks Anju.

Answer (score 0):

The command

`sudo su - hduser`

will take change the user, and take you to the `home` folder of `hduser`.

The command

`sudo su hduser`

can be used to remain in the current working directory even after the user is switched.

Answer (score 0):

Login to ec2 machine as you previously logged in with **ec2-user**, change the permissions of **/home/ec2-user**  , atleast give read permissions to other users.

```
 chmod 777 /home/ec2-user
```

It is not the issue with the folder you are trying to access from the HDFS user.

**ls -ltr** will read the current working directory and will list the files in it.

you switched the user and you are accessing the ec2-user directory (The directory path is same as we required).

After changing the permissions, you are able to see the sub folders in ec2-user aswell.

I hope it will work for you. Please let me know for additional help.